# hibernate Could not determine type for: java.util.List for List<Boolean>

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I am trying to save a list of type Boolean using Hibernate in `Mysql` database. But I keep getting the below error

> failed.org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: xxx_servicesOffered, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(dailyMap)]
>   Could not get session factory

My class looks as follows.

```
public class Services {
private ServicesEnum serviceName;
private ServicesEnum serviceId;
private ServicesCategory serviceCategory;
private List<Boolean> weeKMap;
private List<Boolean> dailyMap;


    ....
       setters and getters
    .

..
```

Does hibernate not allow List of Booleans or is it because of `MySql`? What is the workaround?

Comment: See here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_mapping_types.htm and here section 6.1.1.3: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/types.html

Comment: I tried using annotation @Type(type="org,hibernate.type.NumericalBooleanType") just above my list. But then it cause out of bound error at this statement " dailyMap.set(0, true); "

Comment: What is your mysql attribute type that you are trying to map ?!

Comment: What helped me was adding @ElementCollection above my List, see http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html#collections-ofvalues